# Sequelize Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 (getting started way not CLI)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect ot `mssql` with Sequelize using

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');


const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mssql'
});
```

or

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('msssql://user:pass@example.com:5432');
```

and getting `Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0`

I do not use CLI just getting started code.

regars